# SDL function names?

Tags: c, sdl

So, I'm learning SDL using C.

After mucking around a bit, I managed to get SDL_Init() to give a segmentation fault. After some investigation, it turns out the culprit was that I created a function int connect(). If I rename the function to something else e.g. my_connect(), then everything works fine.

I figured that a function named connect() already exists somewhere in the SDL library and my definition is causing a clash. However, the [API](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_API/) doesn't have any mention of a function named connect or anything like it.

Are there other names I should avoid when using SDL? Where can I find a list of them?

... or is this just another fine example of the need for encapsulation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All SDL names start with SDL_. However, SDL can call standard C functions, such as connect, to function. If your application creates a global function with that name, it replaces the one from the standard library, thus making SDL use yours instead of the global one. Using a different name solves the problem, indeed. Another option would be to make your function static (but then you must not need it globally, of course).